# PHP DOM Web Crawler prints "nothing". no error, nothing

Tags: php

i have been working with web crawler. it worked for few sites,
now when i tried it with this particular site, it came nothing. no error nothing.

i wonder what went wrong..

the code goes as:

```
<?php
    require_once('dom/simple_html_dom.php'); 
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.studentdoc.com/phpBB2/viewforum.php?f=18&sid=2a150b97528c8ec47600692cc77daaf3');
    $elementCount=0;
    foreach($html->find('dl.icon a') as $elemen) {
    foreach($elemen->find('dt a') as $element) {
    $elementCount++;
    $element->href = "http://www.usmleforum.com" . $element->href; 
    echo '<li target="_blank" class="itemtitle">';
    if($elementCount < 5 && $elementCount > 2 && rand(0,1) == 1) {
     echo '<span class="item_new">new</span>';
}
    echo $element;
    echo '</li>';                           
    if($elementCount==12){
       break;
    }
}
}
?>
```

please go through the below given link for HTML structure..

http://www.studentdoc.com/phpBB2/viewforum.php?f=18&sid=2a150b97528c8ec47600692cc77daaf3

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: You should add the troubleshooting steps you've done so far and what the results were.

Comment: nothing man.. it prints nothing

Comment: Add some messages in there. Basic troubleshooting like putting an echo inside each loop to see how far it gets. Turn on error logging and see if you get anything. Check if html has a value after you fetch the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no DOM element like `dl.icon a dt a`. You probably want to fetch `dl.icon dt a`. Remove `a` from first argument in find method.

Always try to debug your code before asking questions. Simple `echo "A"; die(); echo "B"; die();` after every statement will be very helpfull :)

In this case second foreach have 0 elements all the time.

Comment: ohh man.. how did i missed that.. and another.. like you see in my code i put if statement for print only 12 statements from the site.. it kinda not executing.. do you know why

Comment: Becouse $elementCount is always 0

Comment: but in 'for each ' statement i gave `$elementCount++;`

Comment: Move this if statement to first foreach (move one close bracket before if statment). Now you break only second foreach, but first is "elements", second is only "data in element".